# Plot the solution for system of ODEs

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have solved this example available in MATHEMATICA:

```
      eqns = {y'[x] == x^2 y[x], z'[x] == 5 z[x]};
      sol = DSolve[eqns, {y, z}, x] /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
```

I want to:

1) Plot the solution of y and z for different values of the constants c1 and c2 on the interval x in[0,1].

2) Make numerical table for the solution of y&z depend on the point (1).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another option is to use Manipulate (added Print to get the data also)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[y, x, z];
eqns = {y'[x] == x^2 y[x], z'[x] == 5 z[x]};
sol = First@DSolve[eqns, {y[x], z[x]}, x];

Manipulate[
 Module[{sol0, p1, p2, opt, ydata, zdata},
  opt = {GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
    ImageSize -> 300, BaseStyle -> 12};
  sol0 = sol /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2};
  Print[sol0];
  p1 = Plot[{y[x] /. sol0}, {x, 0, xMax}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, 
    Evaluate@opt, PlotStyle -> Red];
  p2 = Plot[{z[x] /. sol0}, {x, 0, xMax}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "z(x)"}, 
    Evaluate@opt];
  ydata = Table[{i, (y[x] /. sol0 /. x -> i)}, {i, 0, xMax, 0.01}];
  zdata = Table[{i, (z[x] /. sol0) /. x -> i}, {i, 0, xMax, 0.01}];
  Print[ydata];
  Print[zdata];
  Grid[{{p1, p2}}]
  ]
 ,
 {{xMax, 0.8, "max x"}, 0.01, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c1, 0.05, "c1"}, -1, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c2, 0.6, "c2"}, -1, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c1, c2, xMax}
 ]
```

Comment: Many thanks Dr.Nasser, the above is really very well-written code and really sorry I am not good in mathematica, as I said yesterday I hope we can do some research papers in the future together. Best regards

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can do something like this:

```
eqns = {y'[x] == x^2 y[x], z'[x] == 5 z[x]};
sol = DSolve[eqns, {y, z}, x] /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2};
ysol[x_, c1_, c2_] = y[x] /. sol;
zsol[x_, c1_, c2_] = z[x] /. sol;
Plot[Evaluate@Table[ysol[x, k, 4], {k, 1., 3., 0.25}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Dear Henrik, many thanks what about getting table output of data?

Comment: Can be done analogously, e.g. `Table[ysol[1., k, l], {k, 1., 3., 0.25}, {l, 1., 3., 0.25}]`

Comment: Many thanks Henrik